# Win7 and multiple monitors: switch focus when moving mouse to different monitor?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, multiple-monitors

I recently upgraded to a dual monitor setup at work, and while the extra real estate is very nice, there's one annoyance: my intuitive reaction is that there are two "active" windows now, namely the topmost window in each monitor -- and I frequently get surprised when keyboard events go to the actual active window, rather than the one I've moused over and am looking at.

There's a setting in the control panel that gives this effect (ease of access -> make the mouse easier to use -> activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse) but it also acts on windows within the same monitor, which I don't want.

I frequently use my ThinkPad's scrolling function on unfocused windows which I *don't* want to receive focus, which come to think of it probably adds to my confusion, since I can scroll my email in the other window but my keyboard shortcuts don't go there.

Is there any way to achieve this effect or am I just wishing?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, get a Mac :-p

In all seriousness OS X does provide this functionality. It might be worth searching for an add on that does the same sort of thing. I know of Wizmouse -- http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/

There might be more though.

AT LAST!!!  Windows 10 has this support :-)

SM

Comment: Do you know what OS X calls it? That might help searches. Also, Wizmouse sounds very interesting -- it endows ThinkPad UltraNav capability on regular mice. No mention of multiple monitors or mouseover, tho.

Comment: This is not exactly the right support (Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Change How Your Mouse Works -> Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse) (win10) - it shoult activate a window only when the mouse move to another monitor.

Comment: @plavozont I tried this but in W10 v.1803(17134.137) it's constantly enabled (even in the same monitor) and not just when switching monitors

Answer (score 0):

You can change the settings to use classic windows appearance etc. and try to focus on the border color of the window.  The board changes on the active window.

I use two monitors and there really isn't much you can do besides change your behavior.

Select things from the taskbar, drag active windows to the same screen and always refer to inactive windows by moving them to the inactive windows monitor and remember to go back to the window you want to be active.